# Trello Drag And Drop Cards Using Scrolling Containers whith PHP MYSQL AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to create a Trello-like frame with 4 lists and cards on which I want to drag and drop cards between those lists, however, I would like to know how can I update the database in Mysql when I drag and drop the elements?
I'm not able to identify how to update ajax and php.

**script.js**

```
var itemContainers = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.board-column-content'));
var columnGrids = [];
var boardGrid;

// Define the column grids so we can drag those
// items around.
itemContainers.forEach(function (container) {

  // Instantiate column grid.
  var grid = new Muuri(container, {
    items: '.board-item',
    layoutDuration: 400,
    layoutEasing: 'ease',
    dragEnabled: true,
    dragSort: function () {
      return columnGrids;
    },
    dragSortInterval: 0,
    dragContainer: document.body,
    dragReleaseDuration: 400,
    dragReleaseEasing: 'ease'
  })
  .on('dragStart', function (item) {
    // Let's set fixed widht/height to the dragged item
    // so that it does not stretch unwillingly when
    // it's appended to the document body for the
    // duration of the drag.
    item.getElement().style.width = item.getWidth() + 'px';
    item.getElement().style.height = item.getHeight() + 'px';
  })
  .on('dragReleaseEnd', function (item) {
    // Let's remove the fixed width/height from the
    // dragged item now that it is back in a grid
    // column and can freely adjust to it's
    // surroundings.
    item.getElement().style.width = '';
    item.getElement().style.height = '';
    // Just in case, let's refresh the dimensions of all items
    // in case dragging the item caused some other items to
    // be different size.
    columnGrids.forEach(function (grid) {
      grid.refreshItems();
    });
  })
  .on('layoutStart', function () {
    // Let's keep the board grid up to date with the
    // dimensions changes of column grids.
    boardGrid.refreshItems().layout();
  });

  // Add the column grid reference to the column grids
  // array, so we can access it later on.
  columnGrids.push(grid);

});

// Instantiate the board grid so we can drag those
// columns around.
boardGrid = new Muuri('.board', {
  layoutDuration: 400,
  layoutEasing: 'ease',
  dragEnabled: true,
  dragSortInterval: 0,
  dragStartPredicate: {
    handle: '.board-column-header'
  },
  dragReleaseDuration: 400,
  dragReleaseEasing: 'ease'
});
```

Comment: Where **exactly** are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use this jKanban boards
In this you can find all events very easily and let me know if you face any issue in this

https://www.riccardotartaglia.it/jkanban/